# Winforms KeyDown function does not work even though I added it to the events

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

Here is the function:

```
 private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
        {
            if (SpielField[ypos + 1][xpos] != '#')
            {
                SpielField[ypos].Replace('@', ' ');
                ypos++;
                string temp = new string(SpielField[ypos].ToCharArray(), 0, xpos);
                temp += '@';
                temp += SpielField[ypos].Substring(xpos + 1);
                SpielField[ypos] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

and here is how I added it to the Events in the constructor:

```
this.KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;
```

I am implementing winforms functions to ConsoleApp but that makes no difference I believe.

Here  is the complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;




namespace MazeProject
{
    class Form1 : Form
    {
        string[] SpielField;
        int column;
        int line;
        int xpos;
        int ypos;
        public Form1(int c,int l,string[] input)
        {
            this.Width = 800;
            this.Height = 800;
            this.column = c;
            this.line = l;
            this.KeyPreview = true;
            SpielField = new string[column];
            SpielField = input;
            for (int i = 0; i < column; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < line; j++)
                {
                    if(SpielField[i][j] == '@')
                    {
                        xpos = j;
                        ypos = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            this.Paint += Form1_Paint;
            this.KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(column);
            for (int i = 0; i < column; i++)
            {
                Font f = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 20, FontStyle.Regular);
                Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(SpielField[i], f, b , 10, 650-(i+2)*40);
            }
        }
        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
            {
                if (SpielField[ypos + 1][xpos] != '#')
                {
                    SpielField[ypos].Replace('@', ' ');
                    ypos++;
                    string temp = new string(SpielField[ypos].ToCharArray(), 0, xpos);
                    temp += '@';
                    temp += SpielField[ypos].Substring(xpos + 1);
                    SpielField[ypos] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filePath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\maze.txt";
            string[] input = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
            int l = Convert.ToInt32(input[0]);
            int c = Convert.ToInt32(input[1]);
            string[] data = new string[c];
            for(int i = 0; i < c; i++)
            {
                data[i] = input[i + 2];
            }
            Form1 game = new Form1(c, l, data);
            Console.WriteLine(c);
            Console.WriteLine(l);

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.Run(game);
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This probably will not function like you intend it to.  There should be no reason to create a Console App just to open a Windows Forms App.  If the entire point of using a Console App is to use an input file.  Just create a `Button` and attach the `ButtonClick` event to an `OpenFileDialog` so that you can choose your text file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to intercept the key events from the form itself you need to set the

```
Form1.KeyPreview = true;
```

otherwise the keys will be intercepted by the current focused control

[Microsoft Docs on KeyPreview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: It still does not work. Is there a problem with the function?

Comment: What do you mean with:  _I am implementing winforms functions to ConsoleApp_? Is this a console app? You have tagged this question with WinForms. Could you explain better your context?

Comment: It is a console app but I'm using the winforms library so as to use drawing functions

Comment: And how do you start the winforms engine? I mean what do you have in your Main method to launch a Winform. Beside, if you need WinForms then why creating a console app that launch a form for drawing?

Comment: Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.Run(game);   I use these methods